# Counting occurrences in nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested

There are some similar questions but being new to python I am not sure how to combine them, hopefully someone can point me in the right way.

I have a nested list, say:
`nested_list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]`
and another nested list containing a string I use for identification later on (name1, name2...) and a string to each of these (aab, abd, abb....):
`another_list = [["name1", "aab..."], ["name2", "abd..."], ["name3", "abb..."], [....`

I need to loop through the strings, starting by taking the first character in each string and count how many times they are in the nested_list. So, taking the first character in string1 (another_list[0][1]), the first character in string2 (another_list[1][1]), and the first character in string3 (another_list[2][1]), corresponding to a, a, a, would return `3, 0, 0`. Same result would come from the second characters, corresponding to a,b,b. The third character from the strings, corresponding to b,d,b, would return `2, 1, 0` and so on until reaching the end of the strings.
I know how to count, for instance, how many times a certain character is in a list but I am not sure about how to loop through a nested list and summing up the result.
Could any of you help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What does "string identifiers and the strings themselves" mean?

Comment: Also, please format your code properly so that strings would be strings not identifiers. Strings are enclosed in quotes, as you might know—this is regardless of language.

Comment: I dont really understand the question or the problem... and I assume I am not the only one `So, the first letter in each string (a,a,a)` ? what where I see no sets of strings that all start with a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you **REALLY** have to learn to formulate your questions clearly, as well as format code an intelligible manner. Currently, your sentences just don't make sense in the context of the sample data/code you've provided.

However...

This does what you need:

```
nested_list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
another_list = [['name0', 'aaa'], ['name1', 'aab'], ['name2', 'abd'], ['name3', 'abb']]

result = [tuple(sum(1 for c in s if c in lst)
                for lst in nested_list)
          for _, s in another_list]
```

and `result` will contain:

```
[(3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (3, 0, 0)]
```

The last part can be expanded to:

```
result = []
for _, s in another_list:
    item = ()
    for lst in nested_list:
        count = 0
        for c in s:
            if c in lst:
                count += 1
        item += (count,)
    result.append(item)
```

but I'd recommend understanding the nested list comprehension (and generator expression) form rather than resorting to the long expanded form.

Comment: hehe how bout `sum(c in lst for c in s)`

Comment: that's an option, although it would be a bit hard to understand for beginners.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the terrible formulation of my question. Partly, because I am not familiar with the python jargon (or coding in general). Anyways, what Erik wrote definitely helped me out. I will see if I can work it out from here. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Python jargon has nothing to do with expressing your questions clearly, but anyway, good luck in the future.